# How do i count how many words there are, and ignore same words in a string? (using method)

Tags: java, string, integer, return

The code here only shows how many words they are, how do i ignore the words that are the same?
For example, "A long long time ago, I
can still remember", would return 8 instead of 9.

I want it to be a method which takes one parameter s of
type String and returns an int value. And im only allowed to use the bacics, so no hash keys or hash set and advance stuff.

```
  public static int mostCommonLetter(String s){

                    int wordCount = 0;

                    boolean word = false;
                    int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;

                    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                       
                        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
                            word = true;
                          
                        } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && word) {
                            wordCount++;
                            word = false;
                          
                        } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
                            wordCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    return wordCount;
                }
}
```

How do i ignore the words that are the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String input = "A long long time ago, I can still remember";
      String[] words = input.split(" ");
      List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String word : words) {
        if (!uniqueWords.contains(word)) {
            uniqueWords.add(word);
        }      
      }
      System.out.println("Number of unique words: " + uniqueWords.size());
    }
}
```

**Output:** *Number of unique words: 8*

Basically, what you can do if you're allowed to use data structures like lists and so on, is create a list and put the words of the input sentence in the list if and only if they aren't already there.

Comment: Sorry for not specifiying but I want it to be a method which takes one parameter s of type String and returns an int value. And im only allowed to use the bacics, so no hash keys and advance stuff. Cheers

Comment: Extracting the relevant parts of that example into a separate method that takes a string as a parameter and returns the number of unique words is trivial. You should edit your question to include all your requirements, however. In particular, what you are allowed and not allowed to use.

Answer (score 1):

General idea:

```
public int getUniqueWords(String input) {
    // Split the string into words using the split() method
    String[] words = input.split(" ");

    // Create a Set to store the unique words
    Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();

    // Loop through the words and add them to the Set
    for (String word : words) {
        uniqueWords.add(word);
    }

    // Return unique words amount
    return uniqueWords.size();
}
```

Same solution using StreamAPI:

```
public int getUniqueWords2(String input) {
    // here we can safely cast to int, because String can contain at most "max int" chars
    return (int) Arrays.stream(input.split(" ")).distinct().count();
}
```

---

If it is needed to handle multiple spaces between words, add some cleanup for `input`:

```
// remove leading and trailing spaces
cleanInput = input.trim();

// replace multiple spaces with a single space
cleanInput = cleanInput.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

---

**Considering the requirement "allowed to use the bacics"**:

1. hashtable (HashSet) is a basic data structure in algorithms
2. problem of **counting unique items** cannot be **logically** solved without a container holding "aready seen" items, so algorithm could check whether the next item is counted or not
3. in the role of container in the simplest case could be a list, but that would cause `O(n^2)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set<T>` collection type, that can only contains unique values:

```
public static int getTotalUniqueWords(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(uniqueWords, words);
    return uniqueWords.size();
}
```

or with Streams:

```
public static long getTotalUniqueWordsStream(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    return Arrays.stream(words).distinct().count();
}
```